# Возможно ли подключиться к серверу по серому внешнему айпи, используя сокет?

Tags: c#, сервер, сокет, ip

Пытаюсь сделать удаленный сервер, взяв за основу вот это:

```
private static IPEndPoint tcpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080);

private static Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

public static void Start()
{
    tcpSocket.Bind(tcpEndPoint);
    tcpSocket.Listen(1);
}
```

На стороне клиента прописан ендпоинт с внешним айпи, который беру парсингом со стороннего сервиса и к которому и пытаюсь прикконектиться, находясь не в локальной сети:

```
var tcpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(" **условные 92.229.121.13** "), 8080);

var tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

tcpSocket.Connect(tcpEndPoint);
```

Проблема в том, что на этапе коннекта просто выдаёт таймаут, нагуглил, что такие проблемы вызывает NAT и ещё куча всякого низкоуровневого софта. Есть решения?

Comment: Есть. Port Forwarding в настройках маршрутизатора.

Comment: Немного теории. Существуют белые и серые ип адреса, так существуют статические и динамические адреса. Не нужно их путать. Белый адрес - это адрес присвоенный непосредственно клиенту, а именно его конечному оборудованию, будь то роутер или просто пк, он может быть как статическим так и динамическим. Статически адрес - это постоянный адрес, который закреплён договором и не меняется с течением времени, в том числе после перезагрузки оборудования.

Comment: Динамические же адреса, это штука не постоянная и может меняться после каждого переподключения к сети провайдера. Для того чтобы отслеживать динамический белый адрес, придумали различные сервисы дднс. Серые ип адреса - адреса которые выдаются клиенту во внутренней сети провайдера. Т. Е. По сути у провайдера стоит где то большой роутер, который раздаёт всем клиентам внутренние адреса, но внешний адрес у таких клиентов у всех одинаковый.

Comment: Если вам необходимо подключение к какому либо пк/программе за пределами дома, то тут нужно понимать, какой у вас адрес. Самое простое - белый статический. Можно подключить пк напрямую проводом от провайдера, и тогда у вас будет полный доступ ко всем портам пк (если конечно не стоит антивирус или фаерволл). Но как правило во всех домашних сетях используют роутер. Грубо говоря, когда вы ставите дома роутер, то вы создаёте сеть с статическими/динамическими СЕРЫМИ адресами, но вы можете управлять всеми входящими запросами и направлять их с помощью своего роутера и функцией проброс портов.

Comment: Если у вас Серый ип от провайдера, то для подключения нужно либо договариваться с ним об пробросе порта до вашего оборудования, что как мне кажется не делается, либо делается но с очень большими потерями как во времени так и в деньгах, либо находиться в одной подсети провайдера, тогда будет возможность подключиться из вне.

Comment: По сути, Серый адрес работает только на исходящие подключения. Как вариант можно использовать впн, либо отдельный сервис установленный на пк с белыми ип, с помощью которого будет происходить общение между клиентами. По типу как это сделано у тимвьювер.

Comment: @Ivan это надо ответом бы оформить, а комментарии удалить.